# mdadm problem on btrfs disks

Tags: ubuntu, partition, btrfs, mdadm

Ubuntu 20.04.1, new reinstall. I accidently tried to mount my BTRFS raid 1 disks using MDADM. I now cannot mount my btrfs raid.

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME                        SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                        55M squashfs          loop  /snap/core18/1880
loop1                      71.3M squashfs          loop  /snap/lxd/16099
loop2                      29.9M squashfs          loop  /snap/snapd/8542
sda                       119.2G                   disk  
├─sda1                        1M                   part  
├─sda2                        1G ext4              part  /boot
└─sda3                    118.2G LVM2_member       part  
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  59.1G ext4              lvm   /
sdb                       465.8G                   disk  
└─sdb1                    465.8G ext4              part  
sdc                         3.7T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md127                     3.7T                   raid1 
  ├─md127p2                 1.2T                   part  
  └─md127p3                 1.9T                   part  
sdd                         3.7T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md127                     3.7T                   raid1 
  ├─md127p2                 1.2T                   part  
  └─md127p3                 1.9T                   part
```

The btrfs disks were `sdc` and `sdd`. I had typed:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

before the problems with `md127`. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

`mdadm --create` doesn't try to mount an MD array, it creates a new one so whatever filesystem was on `sdc` and `sdd` before was destroyed.

If you had btrfs with btrfs RAID (a not btrfs on top of MD RAID) on the disks before, the btrfs metadata were replaced by MD metadata and because you created RAID 1 it did the initial resync destroying even more data saved there.

You might be still able to save some data with [btrfs restore](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Restore) (but that's highly unlikely) or data restore tools like [photorec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoRec) and [testdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk).